# Problem with tables and side captions

Tags: tables, captions

I'm working on putting captions beside a table. When I used SCtable to do so, it messed up the top text on my page and made it appear below the table. Is there any other way I can do this?

Also, how can I put vertical space between the captions; using `\vspace` doesn't have any effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{sidecap,wasysym,array,tabularx,caption}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbox{Date: \underline{\hspace{3cm}}\hfill}\textbox{\hfil \textsc{\LARGE Content}\hfil}\textbox{\hfill}

\vspace{.5cm}

%\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{SCtable}
\caption*{``Caption 1''\\
    ``Caption 2''\\
    ``Caption 3''\\
    ``Caption 4''}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | m{.05mm} |}
    \hline
    Time & Task & Tick \\ \hline
    $00:00 - 01:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $01:00 - 02:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $02:00 - 03:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $03:00 - 04:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $04:00 - 05:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $05:00 - 06:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $06:00 - 07:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $07:00 - 08:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $08:00 - 09:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $09:00 - 10:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $10:00 - 11:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $11:00 - 12:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $12:00 - 13:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $13:00 - 14:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $14:00 - 15:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $15:00 - 16:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $16:00 - 17:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $17:00 - 18:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $18:00 - 19:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $19:00 - 20:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $20:00 - 21:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $21:00 - 22:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $22:00 - 23:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $23:00 - 00:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{SCtable}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.9}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
    & & \textsc{Content} \\
    Sub 1 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 2 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 3 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 4 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 5 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 6 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 7 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 8 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 9 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 10 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 11 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{.3cm}

\mbox{\textsc{Content}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6.5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.9}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star\star\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}

\vspace{.2cm}

Suggestions/Remarks

\underline{\hspace{13cm}}
\underline{\hspace{13cm}}
\underline{\hspace{13cm}}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek :)

Comment: Please, make a complete file with the missing packages and settings. Also putting the float object `SCtable` into `flushleft`, does not make sense, because the table floats away leaving an empty `flushleft` environment.

Comment: Made a complete file and also removed `flushleft` from `SCtable`.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I could write something in the empty space on the right of the box containing stars. :) Should I make use of `twocolumn`?

Comment: I want to add another table on the empty space on the right of the table containing stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to have a non-floating float object:

```
\begin{SCtable}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][h]
```

`\sidecaptionrelwidth` is the default for the first optional parameter, which must be given in order to set the second optional argument.

Example with `Right side` to the right side of the tabular with stars:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{sidecap,wasysym,array,tabularx,caption}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbox{Date: \underline{\hspace{3cm}}\hfill}\textbox{\hfil
\textsc{\LARGE Content}\hfil}\textbox{\hfill}

\vspace{.5cm}

%\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{SCtable}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][h]
\caption*{``Caption 1''\\
    ``Caption 2''\\
    ``Caption 3''\\
    ``Caption 4''}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | m{.05mm} |}
    \hline
    Time & Task & Tick \\ \hline
    $00:00 - 01:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $01:00 - 02:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $02:00 - 03:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $03:00 - 04:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $04:00 - 05:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $05:00 - 06:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $06:00 - 07:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $07:00 - 08:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $08:00 - 09:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $09:00 - 10:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $10:00 - 11:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $11:00 - 12:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $12:00 - 13:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $13:00 - 14:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $14:00 - 15:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $15:00 - 16:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $16:00 - 17:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $17:00 - 18:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $18:00 - 19:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $19:00 - 20:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $20:00 - 21:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $21:00 - 22:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $22:00 - 23:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    $23:00 - 00:00$ & & $\Box$ \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{SCtable}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.9}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
    & & \textsc{Content} \\
    Sub 1 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 2 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 3 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 4 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 5 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 6 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 7 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 8 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 9 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 10 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
    Sub 11 & $\Box$ & \hrulefill \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{.3cm}

\mbox{\textsc{Content}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6.5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.9}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ &
$\star\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star\star\star$
\hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ & $\star\star\star\star\star$ \hspace{.5cm} $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}\quad
Right side

\vspace{.2cm}

Suggestions/Remarks

\underline{\hspace{13cm}}
\underline{\hspace{13cm}}
\underline{\hspace{13cm}}

\end{flushleft}
```

> [image: Result page 1]

Comment: Sorry, I meant the empty space above it, sorry. And `\vspace` messes up the distance between captions when I put sentences as captions, is there any other way I can put spaces between the captions?

Comment: @VinayakMehta Pretty unclear to me. The captions 1 to 4 are separated by ```\\```, this could be changed to ```\\[1cm]``` to add additional space.

Comment: I'm trying to make the captions evenly spaced along the height of the table, will do what you said and report back.

Comment: That worked! Thanks @HeikoOberdiek! :D Just one last question, to put a table in that empty space above star table, should I just follow the normal way? Guess I'll have to try first but it would be awesome if you could give some pointers. Thanks again!

Comment: @VinayakMehta You can put the tabular in the same line as the left tabular. There is an optional argument of `tabular` for the vertical alignment (`t` = top, `b` = bottom, default is centered).

Comment: I had some questions regarding the layout of this page, should I ask a separate question or continue in this thread?

Comment: @VinayakMehta It depends on the questions. If the questions address new different issues, than new clear questions are often better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27738/discussion-between-vinayak-mehta-and-heiko-oberdiek).